# How does Hibernate Metamodel Generator work?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Recently just making a move from Hibernate Session api to JPA2.  I am assuming it should be some setup problem. But basically my eclipse does not recognize Metamodel attribute.

For example: `builder.like( root.get(Book_.name) , search)`  Book_ can not be resolved as variable.

Now I have followed this http://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/  and added

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

As it stated here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html

> In most cases the annotation processor will automatically run provided the processor jar is added to the build classpath

I have checked my build path it included all maven dependency including jpamodelgen, but my eclipse still say Book_ can not be resolved.

What am I doing wrong here?

This is my Dao...

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Book> criteria = builder.createQuery(Book.class);

    Root<Book> root = criteria.from(Book.class);

    criteria.select(root);

    if( search != null && !search.isEmpty() ){

        criteria.where(builder.add(
                builder.like( root.get(Book_.name) , search),  // Book_ cannot be resolved a variable
                builder.like(root.get(Book_.ispn), search)    //  ""
                )
        );

    }

    List<Book> books = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

    return books;
```

My dependency

```
   <properties>
    <spring-version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring-version>
    <hibernate-version>5.2.6.Final</hibernate-version> 
   </properties>  
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-orm-modules</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.40</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your target doesn't contains the generated classed you need to configure maven processor like in the documentation that you [provided](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html#_usage_with_maven).

If your target contains the generated classes, then all you have to to do is to add them your classpath :
if you are using eclipse:

1. Right click on your project
2. Properties
3. Java build path
4. Add folder
5. choose the folder under target/generated-sources that contains the generated MetaModel
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Rafik solution does work but I just wanted to add another method that also worked for me is to enable annotation processing in your eclipse project.  The doc from hibernate https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html  wasn't really clear to me as it doesn't have step by step setup.  So here is how I did it.

This is project specific.

1. Click on project.
2. Right click and chose properties
3. Java Compiler> Annotation Processing :: enable this
4. Java Compiler> Annotation Processing> FactoryPath  select add External JARS
5. Add hibernate-jpamodelgen-x.x.x.Final.jar
6. Click okey / clean project

This should work as well.

Hope this helps others

**Update**
I stumbled upon this site that has pictures might be easier to follow. 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html